# Programatically create UI in UI thread from Background thread and copy it to background thread again?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

Here is how I started a new thread:

```
  private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread myThread = new System.Threading.Thread(prePrint);
            myThread.Start();                    
        }
```

the prePrint function goes like this:

```
 private void prePrint()
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < DataHandle.Recipe.Count; j++)
            {
                // create print dialog
                // create print ticket.
                FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();

                // assign the createFD(int j) to fd here. << HERE IS THE MAIN PROBLEM

                DocumentPaginator sd = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)fd).DocumentPaginator;

                 // print the flow document here

            }
         }


  private FlowDocument createFD(int j) {

                                          FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();
                                          return fd;

                                        }
```

I want to create flow document in UI thread and copy it to background thread and finally print it (if possible).

I am very new to this technology. Please help me to find the better way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the basic trick is to use `Dispatcher` of a `FlowDocument` and call the function with `BeginInvoke()`.  By the way the document can be created only on UI thread and used on thread where it was created, but this can be optimized, if the document structure first constructed and after saved into in memory `XML`.  Doubt a little bit on performance of this, you should check it.

Look here, a good example imo: http://chrismylonas.blogspot.com/2007/12/flowdocument-and-multiple-threads.html

Comment: I think yes. But as much saving in memory as marshalling saved stream between threads. But is this will relevant for you or not, depends on your app. You should measure it. If the document is too big, you can try to save it into temporary `MemoryMappedFile` and after load from it. *Could be faster*. But measure.